# buffer overflow while writing to char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, ascii, buffer-overflow

Could anyone help me out here? 
I don't really know why this code doesn't work properly. 
Just want to split a string in two. However, somehow strange thing happen that it writes `6 char` instead of `3 char`. The for loop executes `3 times`.

---

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char array[100] = "aaa-aaaaa";
    char first[100];
    char last[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++){
        if(array[i] == 45){
            for(int a = 0; a < i; a++){
                first[a] = array[a];
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < (strlen(array) - (i+1)); a++){
            last[a] = array[(a+i+1)];
        }

        }
    }
    printf("%s and the length is %d\n", first, strlen(first));
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(first); i++){
        printf("%d ", first[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%s and the length is %d\n", last, strlen(first));
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(last); i++){
        printf("%d ", last[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
aaa�� and the length is 6
97 97 97 -76 -1 127 
aaaaa and the length is 6
97 97 97 97 97 %
```

Comment: Every string has to be terminated with `\0` character.

Comment: yes. But first char array should only have 3 chars in it not 6. As far as i know "\0" is not printed out

Comment: It is not printed out. But where do you put it in your `first` array?

Comment: but all of the string functions need zero terminated chars array. As you do not terminate it ,it is the UB

Comment: @Artiom, you aren't terminating the `last` buffer with a zero.  You could either explicitly terminate it outside of your loop, ie: `last[a]=0` (declare a outside of the loop) or you could memset all of first and last to zero before you operate on them.

Comment: Also, either your curly braces are messed up or your indentation is messed up.  Notice that the closing curly brace to the first inner for loop is on the same column as the inner if statement.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Even simpler than `memset`, just initialize with `{0}`.

Comment: @MFisherKDX honestly didint knew that i need to explicitly terminate char array ^^

Comment: You don't *always* need to terminate char array. You need to terminate something you intend to use with C string functions.

Comment: In addition to other logic flaws in setting up your `first` and `last` character strings, the print at the bottom is also wrong: `printf("\n%s and the length is %d\n", last, strlen(first));` ==> `printf("\n%s and the length is %d\n", last, strlen(last));`

Comment: Why not try `strtok*()`? Type `man strtok` to see the usage.

Answer (score 1):

After the first for is finished add this: `first[a]='\0';`
strlen is calculated by iterating from the first element to `\0`.

```
unsigned int firstLen=0, secLen=0;
while(array[firstLen]!='-'){
    first[firstLen] = array[firstLen];
    firstLen++;
}
first[firstLen]='\0';
secLen=firstLen;
while(array[secLen]!='\0'){
    last[secLen-firstLen] = array[secLen];
    secLen++;
}
last[secLen-firstLen]='\0';
```

Comment: The same mechanism is also used when you are trying to print a string with prinft.